# What is the best method to change an img src using javascript with django?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I can get the img src to change using onclick and a hard path without django template tags. It's my impression this is bad practice. How can I get "{% static 'indv_proj\Metron Pres\Slide3.JPG' %}" format injected/changed into the html img src everytime I click the image?

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#indv-ppt").click(function(){
            // Change src attribute of image
            $(this).attr("src", "{% static 'indv_proj\Metron Pres\Slide3.JPG' %}");
        });
    });
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="ppt-slides">
    <img id= indv-ppt src="{% static 'indv_proj\Metron Pres\Slide1.JPG' %}"  alt="Error">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ppt-slides">
   <img src="{% static 'indv_proj\Metron Pres\Slide1.JPG' %}" id="indv-ppt" alt="Error" data-original="{% static 'indv_proj\Metron Pres\Slide3.JPG' %}" onclick="imgchange()">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function imgchange(){
    var element = document.getElementById("indv-ppt");
    var src = element.getAttribute("data-original");
    element.setAttribute("src", src);
}
```

I don't know much Jquery but I hope you get the logic.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file, try putting double-quotes around your id value:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="ppt-slides">
    <img id= "indv-ppt" src="{% static 'indv_proj\Metron Pres\Slide1.JPG' %}"  alt="Error">
  </div>
```

Also, it is a good practice for beginners to print something on the console to determine where the bug actually lies.